# How do I unit test the result of a 'then' of a promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using TypeScript to write a very simple service that utilizes the AWS SDK. My Jest unit tests are passing, but the coverage reports are saying that the line 'return result.Items' is not covered. Can anyone tell why this is? Is it a bug in jest?

```
// service file

/**
 * Gets an array of documents.
 */
function list(tableName) {
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName,
  };
  return docClient
    .scan(params)
    .promise()
    .then((result) => {
      return result.Items;
    });
}

// test file

const stubAwsRequestWithFakeArrayReturn = () => {
  return {
    promise: () => {
      return { then: () => ({ Items: 'fake-value' }) };
    },
  };
};

it(`should call docClient.scan() at least once`, () => {
  const mockAwsCall = jest.fn().mockImplementation(stubAwsRequest);
  aws.docClient.scan = mockAwsCall;
  db.list('fake-table');
  expect(mockAwsCall).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});

it(`should call docClient.scan() with the proper params`, () => {
  const mockAwsCall = jest.fn().mockImplementation(stubAwsRequest);
  aws.docClient.scan = mockAwsCall;
  db.list('fake-table');
  expect(mockAwsCall).toBeCalledWith({
    TableName: 'fake-table',
  });
});

it('should return result.Items out of result', async () => {
  const mockAwsCall = jest
    .fn()
    .mockImplementation(stubAwsRequestWithFakeArrayReturn);
  aws.docClient.get = mockAwsCall;
  const returnValue = await db.get('fake-table', 'fake-id');
  expect(returnValue).toEqual({ Items: 'fake-value' });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line not covered is the success callback passed to `then`.

Your mock replaces `then` with a function that doesn't accept any parameters and just returns an object.  The callback from your code is passed to the `then` mock during the test but it doesn't call the callback so `Jest` correctly reports that the callback is not covered by your tests.

Instead of trying to return a mock object that *looks* like a `Promise`, just return an actual resolved `Promise` from your mock:

```
const stubAwsRequestWithFakeArrayReturn = () => ({
  promise: () => Promise.resolve({ Items: 'fake-value' })
});
```

...that way `then` will still be the actual [`Promise.prototype.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and your callback will be called as expected.

---

You should also `await` the returned `Promise` to ensure that the callback has been called before the test completes:

```
it(`should call docClient.scan() at least once`, async () => {
  const mockAwsCall = jest.fn().mockImplementation(stubAwsRequest);
  aws.docClient.scan = mockAwsCall;
  await db.list('fake-table');  // await the Promise
  expect(mockAwsCall).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});

it(`should call docClient.scan() with the proper params`, async () => {
  const mockAwsCall = jest.fn().mockImplementation(stubAwsRequest);
  aws.docClient.scan = mockAwsCall;
  await db.list('fake-table');  // await the Promise
  expect(mockAwsCall).toBeCalledWith({
    TableName: 'fake-table',
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a great answer, and props for noticing I was forgetting to 'await' the test completion.

Comment: @SimonStiph you're welcome, glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The Library chai-as-promised is worth looking at.

https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

> Instead of manually wiring up your expectations to a promise’s
>   fulfilled and rejected handlers.

```
doSomethingAsync().then(
    function (result) {
        result.should.equal("foo");
        done();
    },
    function (err) {
       done(err);
    }
);
```

> you can write code that expresses what you really mean:

```
return doSomethingAsync().should.eventually.equal("foo");
```